# Connecting to GP Web service throws exception

Tags: c#, web-services, dynamics-gp

I'm trying connect to GP webservice to create sales order from C# application. But When I try to connect it is throwing exception as below.

```
The application encountered an unhandled system exception.  Contact your system administrator for details.
```

Below is my app.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="GPWebService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
        openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
        sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
        transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
        messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8"
        useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192"
          maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096"
          maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
          enabled="false" />
          <security mode="Message">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"
            proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows"
            negotiateServiceCredential="true" algorithmSuite="Default"
            establishSecurityContext="true" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://WSGP:48620/Dynamics/GPService/GPService"
      binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="GPWebService"
      contract="GPWebService.DynamicsGP" name="GPWebService">
        <identity>
          <userPrincipalName value="WSGP\Administrator" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

C# Code consuming the service

```
CompanyKey companyKey;
            Context context;
            SalesOrder salesOrder;
            SalesDocumentTypeKey salesOrderType;
            CustomerKey customerKey;
            BatchKey batchKey;
            SalesOrderLine salesOrderLine;
            ItemKey orderedItem;
            Quantity orderedAmount;
            Policy salesOrderCreatePolicy;
            // Create an instance of the service
            DynamicsGPClient wsDynamicsGP = new DynamicsGPClient();
            // Create a context with which to call the service
            wsDynamicsGP.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "admin";
            wsDynamicsGP.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "pass";
            wsDynamicsGP.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = "WSGP";
            System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBinding binding;
            binding = new System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBinding(System.ServiceModel.SecurityMode.None);
            //wsDynamicsGP.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = "wsgp";
            context = new Context();
            // Specify which company to use (sample company)
            companyKey = new CompanyKey();
            companyKey.Id = (-1);
            // Set up the context object
            context.OrganizationKey = (OrganizationKey)companyKey;
            // Create a sales order object
            salesOrder = new SalesOrder();
            // Create a sales document type key for the sales order
            salesOrderType = new SalesDocumentTypeKey();
            salesOrderType.Type = SalesDocumentType.Order;
            // Populate the document type key of the sales order object
            salesOrder.DocumentTypeKey = salesOrderType;
            // Create a customer key
            customerKey = new CustomerKey();
            customerKey.Id = "121001";
            // Set the customer key property of the sales order object
            salesOrder.CustomerKey = customerKey;
            // Create a batch key
            batchKey = new BatchKey();
            batchKey.Id = "RMS";
            // Set the batch key property of the sales order object
            salesOrder.BatchKey = batchKey;
            // Create a sales order line to specify the ordered item
            salesOrderLine = new SalesOrderLine();
            // Create an item key
            orderedItem = new ItemKey();
            orderedItem.Id = "8011172009618";
            // Set the item key property of the sales order line object
            salesOrderLine.ItemKey = orderedItem;
            // Create a sales order quantity object
            orderedAmount = new Quantity();
            orderedAmount.Value = 4;
            // Set the quantity of the sales order line object
            salesOrderLine.Quantity = orderedAmount;
            // Create an array of sales order lines
            // Initialize the array with sales order line object
            SalesOrderLine[] orders = { salesOrderLine };
            // Add the sales order line array to the sales order
            salesOrder.Lines = orders;
            // Get the create policy for the sales order object
            salesOrderCreatePolicy = wsDynamicsGP.GetPolicyByOperation("CreateSalesOrder", context);
            // Create the sales order
            wsDynamicsGP.CreateSalesOrder(salesOrder, context, salesOrderCreatePolicy);
            // Close the service
            if (wsDynamicsGP.State != CommunicationState.Faulted)
            {
                wsDynamicsGP.Close();
            }
```

GP Config file is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="cachingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Dynamics.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.Configuration.CacheManagerSettings, Microsoft.Dynamics.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
  </configSections>
  <cachingConfiguration configSource="WSCachingConfiguration.config"/>
  <appSettings file="WSServiceAppSettings.config">
    <add key="SecurityRuntimeAuditQueuing" value="0"/>
    <add key="SecurityRuntimeAuditingIsActive" value="false"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings configSource="WSBindings.config"/>
    <services>
      <service name="Microsoft.Dynamics.GP.WebServices.Contract.DynamicsGP" behaviorConfiguration="GPWCFStaticMetadataBehavior">
        <endpoint address="Mex" name="http" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <endpoint address="GPService" name="GPWebService" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBindingTarget" contract="Microsoft.Dynamics.GP.WebServices.Contract.IGPServices"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://WSGP:48620/Dynamics/GPService"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="GPWCFStaticMetadataBehavior">
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentSessions="1024"/>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" externalMetadataLocation="http://WSGP:48620/Metadata/WCF/Full/schemas.microsoft.com.dynamics.gp.2010.01.wsdl"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication cacheLogonTokens="true"/>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="GPDynamicMetadataBehavior">
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentSessions="1024"/>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication cacheLogonTokens="true"/>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <client/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <switches>
      <add name="ApplicationTraceSwitch" value="0"/>
    </switches>
    <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
      <listeners>
        <add name="dynamicsListener"/>
      </listeners>
    </trace>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="" propagateActivity="true">
        <!--Values can be:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx -->
        <listeners>
          <add name="wcfListener"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.IO.Log">
        <listeners>
          <add name="wcfListener"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.Runtime.Serialization">
        <listeners>
          <add name="wcfListener"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.IdentityModel">
        <listeners>
          <add name="wcfListener"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="wcfListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics\GPWebServices\Logs\Tracing\GPWebServices.svclog"/>
      <add name="dynamicsListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics\GPWebServices\Logs\Tracing\GPWebServices.log"/>
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

What I'm doing wrong here? Am I missing something in the configuration file ?

I should say, I'm novice to Web services development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the issue because I was passing wrong Company ID, I got the exception details from DynamicWebserviceExceptionConsole. When I tried to pass a proper company ID this is working.

Answer (score 1):

For such error, you need to go to Dynamics "Web Services Exceptions" Console. There you will be able to see details of that error.
To open it, find it here:

> C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative
>   Tools\Dynamics GP Web Service Exception Management Console

or

> "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Microsoft
>   Dynamics\ManagementConsole\DynamicsWebServicesExceptionsConsole.msc"